# Setting unicode encoding in Windows doesn't work

Tags: java, windows, encoding, utf-8

Under windows when I try to read and display unicode UTF-8 characters, I get:

```
>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

>java ReadRussianCharacters
??????
```

If I set encoding to 1251, then I can read them correctly:

```
>chcp 1251
Active code page: 1251

>java ReadRussianCharacters
Привет
```

I have already set the console fonts to Lucida Console before trying this and my Java code also specifies UTF-8 before reading the file:

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(File), "UTF-8")
```

So, why doesn't UTF-8 (chcp 65001) works?

I have been trying this for years now and I was never able to display UTF-8 correctly.

Comment: What console? `cmd.exe`? Most often this is console issue, not Java issue.

Comment: That is the console, yes.

Comment: The console is basically a legacy component, it has had very little work done on it in the last few decades and lately there's talk of it being replaced by Powershell.  It has never supported Unicode properly.  Your best bet IMO is to write yourself a GUI, Java makes this pretty easy.  Or try Powershell, or a third-party console replacement.